# In App Purchase - Long waiting times (up to 10 seconds) sometimes for first popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, rmstore

We're using the RMStore framework (https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) in our game app to do In-App Purchases on iOS.

Sometimes between issuing the In-App Purchase and getting a feedback (showing the system popup to start the Purchase) takes up to 10 seconds. This is kind of rare but on some days it's really bad, while on others it's very fast.

Is there anything we can do about to have it always fast?

Do you/others also experience this issue?

Here's the code we use to start a purchase:

```
[[RMStore defaultStore] addPayment: [NSString stringWithUTF8String:productIdentifier.c_str()] success: ^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {

    this->onPurchaseInAppProductSuccessInner(productIdentifier, [=](InAppPurchaseProductResult result) {

        callback(result);
    });

} failure:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction, NSError *error) {
    MLLOG("[AccountManager] Purchase Error");

}];
```

Comment: Yeah, I also facing the same issue. It sounds like user clicked on the button and it is not working. After doing heavy R&D I found somewhere that it is due to latency difference from the device to the apple server. But I do not know why other many standard apps works fine with the same device same network same ID.

Comment: Are you talking about production or sandbox? The sandbox is always broken and slow and unreliable, production too sometimes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863889/in-app-purchase-takes-too-long-time-to-show-confirmation-alert-view

Comment: I think this question has been answered before... ^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-App-Purchase takes too long time to show confirmation alert view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863889/in-app-purchase-takes-too-long-time-to-show-confirmation-alert-view)

Comment: @Gruntcakes Yes, I'm testing sandbox here. I wasn't aware that it is much slower than production. I was mainly afraid that production would be the same then.